# "Invalid Member Id" on Android and on API console works normally

Tags: android, linkedin-api, retrofit

I use a [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to manage REST communication with LinkedIn.

Decline a interface

```
public interface LinkedInManager {
    String BASE_URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1";

    @GET("/people/~")
    Profile getUserInfo();

    @GET("/people/id={id}")
    void getUserInfo(@Path("id") String id, Callback<Profile> cb);
}
```

i try to getting a UserInfo

```
 RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
        builder
                .setEndpoint(LinkedIn.BASE_URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson())).setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

        final String accessToken = getIntent().getExtras().getString(PACKAGE_NAME + ".accessToken");
        if (accessToken != null) {
            builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addQueryParam("oauth2_access_token", accessToken);
                    request.addQueryParam("format", "json");
                }
            });
        }
        builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
        final LinkedIn linkedIn = restAdapter.create(LinkedIn.class);
        linkedIn.getUserInfo("cQEjnKL6pD",callback);
```

and when i send a request i get an

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Invalid member id {cQEjnKL6pD}",
  "requestId": "MYEIGI80KX",
  "status": 404,
  "timestamp": 1426989602678
}
```

But when i check this method in [LinkedIn API Console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) all works fine.

Request from my app :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=cQEjnKL6pD?oauth2_access_token=AQUjGuS8emH9DaZAkRtTtD8LgLnyApDoRhEc_8czX_8zRGngjiBahKBS15Y2rTCyL4rJHQMe7NYDZTECph59PCVCzaKSvosKevKqVyQwsXmMtEH-Abf3GyqPiNAfSswzvRU_nCW5ToEY-DgGiNif4V-JEyh99JuxNPPAIehE8Vi47oJOyl0&format=json
```

Request from console :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=cQEjnKL6pD?oauth2_access_token=AQVZh_28bwO32ja2s3Kn0AzqYh3LyM_xqpTMXMshYawAvgjSYhl0GRDtxOjnFTscxqLtVMzxHl8J6EFJagwq1rUAR1_GCtZvMLxxkPOoBlpkj04T43aphfUDy85a6gyDTjxxZjBtKsCtasd95aEwoAm8M0PFfxAjYxWvoIOW1i3xDDDfYKo&format=json
```

Both give to me different result. First - **"Invalid member id"**, Second - works normal. Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future searches.

According to [LinkedIn API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) :

> **id** A unique identifying value for the member.
>
> **This value is linked to your specific application.**  Any attempts to use it with a different application will result in a "404 - Invalid member id" error.